# New line and spaces automatically inserted in String

Tags: java, string, authorization, httpurlconnection

For authentication with an API I created a encoded string containing the email and password of a user like so:

```
String userpass = u[0].getEmail() + ":" + u[0].getPassword();
userpass = Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
String basicAuth = "Basic " + userpass;
HttpUrlConnection conn = new HttpUrlConnection(); 
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

the problem is that once this string is generated, new lines and spaces are added which makes the string look like this:

Authorization: Basic dHJpc3RhbkBjb3BheS5jb206MTA3ZDM0OGJmZjQzN2M5OTlhOWZmMTkyYWRjYjc4Y2IwM2I4ZGRj
      Ng==

[image: Screenshot from android studio showing the "conn.getRequestProperty"]

This is causing the API to only see the first part only (not the "Ng==" part), which leads to the fact that the server think the email and password are faulty.

I already tried every possible form of String.Replace and ReplaceAll but that didn't seem to help.

A suggestion was to fix the string on the API itself but that is no option due to the fact that the API doesn't receive the whole string.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance

Comment: what makes you say there's newlines and spaces? How did you check that? Show the code you printed that with

Comment: When i decode your string from Base64  the output is 'tristan@copay.com:107d348bff437c999a9ff192adcb78cb03b8ddc6'. 

Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, the password is a Sha1 hash of the password "Azerty123"
I also added a screenshot of android studio showing a lof of the conn.getRequestProperty

Comment: It's the normal behaviour. From [RFC4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-3.1) `MIME enforces a limit on line length of base 64-encoded data to 76 characters`.

Comment: Where are you getting this `Base64` class from? Java 8 introduced `java.util.Base64` but you aren't using that (it has no `encodeToString()` method)... so whose `Base64` are you using?

Comment: @SubOptimal so is there a way to make it work with the string that we have or de we have to use an other encryption mechanism. 
if that's not an option shortening the string could be something to look into

Comment: It was the android.util.Base64

Comment: Base64 is **not** encryption, it is just encoding. Encryption requires a key to encrypt and decrypt, Base64 does not.

Answer (score 0):

I feel quite stupid for this but Base64 actually has a way to make this work.
The encryption method just had to be set to "Base64.No_WRAP" instead of "Base64_DEFAULT".
Was considering removing the question but if someone ever has a similar problem i hope it will save them some time.